# Basic MEF workflow/usage

Tags: .net, plugins, mono, mef, extensibility

I'm looking to a framework which will allow me to have a simple plugin system in my .NET application. It seems MEF is the framework which Microsoft is endorsing, and will become part of .NET 4 (it also seems to work with older .NET versions as a separate library, as well as Mono).

I'm previously used Mono.Addins as for a plugin system for a different project. The basic idea is I define a set of interfaces, these become "extension points", a plugin API if you will for the application.

Can MEF be used in a similar manner? How can I get started with MEF, especially from the perspective of someone with experience with Mono.Addins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and I posted an example of how to do what you're talking about with MEF in a CodeProject article: [Building an Extensible Application with MEF, WPF, and MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/SoapBoxCorePinBallDemo.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [MEF CodePlex Site](http://mef.codeplex.com/)?  The [Programming Guide](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guide) there is a pretty good place to get started.

Comment: +1 The MEF Codeplex site does provide a lot of good, clean examples of how to use the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Will an IOC utility work for your needs? I've found [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) really straight forward.